# Sequence generated by averaging adjacent terms first increases then decreases

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, means

Consider the sequence $s_0=(7,2,1,5,6)$, taking the mean of adjacent terms to form the next sequence $s_1=(\frac{7+2}{2},\frac{2+1}{2},\frac{1+5}{2},\frac{5+6}{2},\frac{6+7}{2})=(4.5,1.5,3,5.5,6.5)$, and similarly
$$
s_2=(3,2.25,4.25,6,5.5)\\
s_3=(2.625,3.25,{5.125},\color{red}{5.75},4.25)
$$

The terms of the sequence $s_3$ increases first and then decreases. This pattern tends to occur for any sequence of integers after some steps.

ie., $s_i(1)\le s_i(2)\le\cdots \le s_i(k-1)\le s_i(k)\ge s_i(k+1)\cdots$ at least under a cyclic shift, after a finite $i$.

How do I justify such a pattern for a general case of integers ?

Another example: $s_0=(7,1,4,5,0)$ then
$$
s_1 = (4, 2.5, 2, 3.5)\\
s_2 = (3.25, 2.25, 2.75, 3.75)\\
s_3 = (2.75, 2.5, 3.25, 3.5)\\
s_4 = (2.625, 2.875, \color{red}{3.375}, 3.125)
$$

**My Observations**

The average of the terms remains the same, in this case $s_i^{avg}=4.2$ for all $i$, which is not difficult to prove. That means, the data are just being redistributed in each step.

$$
s_0=(s_0(0),s_0(2),s_0(3),\cdots,s_0(n-2),s_0(n-1))\\
s_1=(\frac{s_0(0)+s_0(1)}{2},\frac{s_0(1)+s_0(2)}{2},\frac{s_0(2)+s_0(3)}{2},\cdots,\frac{s_0(n-1)+s_0(0)}{2})
$$
Let $d_k(i)=s_k(i+1)-s_{k}(i)$ then $s_{k+1}(i)=\dfrac{s_k(i)+s_k(i+1)}{2}=\dfrac{s_k(i)+s_{k}(i)+d_k(i)}{2}=s_k(i)+\dfrac{d_k(i)}{2}$

and similarly, $d_{k+1}(i)=\dfrac{s_k(i+2)-s_k(i)}{2}$

Generating sequences by taking the mean of the adjacent terms move the terms closer together, ie., over the steps the values must tend to be more uniform around the mean of the sequence.

But, are there anything else causing this pattern to occur?

Comment: If you write out the algebra (IE Start with $(a, b, c, d, e)$), then you can quickly figure out what causes there to be only 1 peak value.  $quad$ For example, if you start with $(7, 1, 5, 6, 2)$, then $s_3$ has a plateau (so not quite an immediate counterexample, but enough to question if your conclusion is truly valid).

Comment: @CalvinLin The end pattern tend to be bitonic, ie., equality is possible, and I just edited the post.

Comment: @CalvinLin I tried with many sequence of integers, and the results seems to be either increasing then decreasing, or increasing, or just constant. But, none remained as some random fluctuations.

Comment: You are repeatedly multiplying an initial vector $(a\ b\ c\ \dotsc\ z)$ by a matrix $$\pmatrix{1/2&1/2&0&\dotsc&0\cr0&1/2&1/2&\dotsc&0\cr\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots\cr1/2&0&\dotsc&0&1/2\cr}$$ The chances are the answer to your question lies in the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of this matrix.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Could you provide more insight into the possible influence of eigenvalues and vectors into justifying the formation of such a pattern when repeatedly applying this matrix?

Comment: Suppose, for example, that a matrix $A$ has an eigenvector $v$ with eigenvalue one, and all the other eigenvalues are less than one in modulus. Then for all vectors $x$, $A^nx$ converges to a multiple of $v$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Okay. These are markov matrices which has the elements in each column sum to 1. Has an eigenvalue 1 with eigenvector $(1,1,1,\cdots,1)$, and therefore $A^nx$ converges to the eigenvector $(1,1,1,\cdots,1)$ corresponds to the eigenvalue 1. This explains my second observation that the terms move closer together and become more uniform around the mean. But, how do we justify the occurence of increasing decreasing pattern ?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Can we atleast have an inductive proof for this ?

Comment: @SoorajS "*how do we justify the occurrence of increasing decreasing pattern*" $\;-\;$ It is not clear whether you claim the pattern occurs after some number $n_0$ of steps, or that it occurs for all $n \ge n_0$.

Comment: @dxiv I don't mean a particular $n_0$. The pattern tends to occur after a finite number of iterations for any sequence of integers. I could not find any counter examples so this seems to be true generally. But, I am trying to understand why this occurs.

Comment: @SoorajS I understand that $n_0$ depends on the initial sequence. But my question was whether the pattern holds for all $n \ge n_0$ or just $n_0$ (and perhaps other, but not all, $n \gt n_0\,$).

Comment: @dxiv It holds for all $n\ge n_0$.sometimes it leads to uniform distribution, so I am talking about including that.

Comment: @SoorajS Each step is taking a moving average of the previous sequence, which is a simple type of convolution, and iterating it eventually approaches a Gaussian, see for example, [1](https://www.datasciencecentral.com/moving-averages-natural-weights-iterated-convolutions-and-central/), [2](https://nghiaho.com/?p=1159), [3](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/49583/gaussian-equivalent-of-convolving-an-image-50-times-with-a-box-filter). This is not a proof, of course, just some insight from a different angle.

Comment: @dxiv Do you think that we can justify the generation of bitonic pattern from the central limit theorem ?

Comment: @SoorajS The limit is Gaussian by CLT, though it can also be proved independently. However, formalizing this to answer the question here is not exactly trivial, and it would in fact prove a far more general statement for arbitrary sequences and weighted averages.

Comment: @dxiv, don't you think it's a Markov chain, converging to a multiple of the all-ones eigenvector?

Comment: @GerryMyerson yup. But it only explains it becoming a uniform distribution as $t\to\infty$.

Comment: But, Sooraj, I'm saying it's uniform, @dxiv is saying it's Gaussian. Those can't both be right, can they?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I left the comment here hoping someone better versed may see more into it, but I am nowhere near working out a full answer off it. FWIW my first thought was not even about probabilities, but rather box ([averaging](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/3202/averaging-filters)) filters in signal processing, since the wrap-around averaging in OP's question amounts to convolution proper of the associated periodic infinite sequence.

Comment: @dxiv, the wrap-around averaging amounts to multiplication by the matrix I gave earlier.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Right, and an explicit form of the sequence can be derived from the powers of that matrix and, ultimately, its eigenvalues (as you wrote), though the calculations may not be the prettiest.